# I cant use click() function in selenium jupyter notebook

Tags: python, selenium

I wnt get site and click all car ads but click() function not working, I want click ads and get values about cars.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url="http://www.auto.az/cars/page/1"
driver.get(url)

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url="http://www.auto.az/cars/page/1"
driver.get(url)

i=1
while i<=20:
    
 araba=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li[{}]").format(str(i))
    araba.click()
    i+=1
```

My code like that,  I want click every ad one by one but this function not working
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try `print(araba)` to see what exactly is found.

Comment: i do but it comes [] i forget to add here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = "http://www.auto.az/cars/page/1"
driver.get(url)

cars = driver.find_element_by_class_name("car-block").find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for araba in cars:
    araba.find_element_by_class_name("title").find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```

Maybe put urls of the cars to a set or list and then navigate.

EDIT:

```
for i in range(1,21):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a").click()
```

Comment: yes it is worked, but why my code didnt work everything was true and simple ?and thank you :)

Comment: I edited my anwser. The "f" before the string is the same as .format , just less syntax.

Comment: I understand thank you, and can u help me for take values values right side from photo I took motor size,year,price with beautiful soup but for get color and ban type I need selenium u solved id thank u but can  I get values from table?

Comment: ``` banlar=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='car_ad']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")``` i use this type for get ban type but still gives me empty list

Comment: use find_element_by_xpath(banlar_xpath).text instead of elements

Comment: i get error  Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression                             hey can we talk in  another app discord is ok for u?

Comment: sure add me bilke#1227